# Angularjs: Error posting data. Variable undefined

Tags: angularjs

This must be something really silly. I cannot get a simple form to work.
Worked through the bunch of links that google spits out but none helped.
I alwajs get the $scope.user undefined below.

This is the form ...

```
<form name="login" ng-submit="submitLogin()" ng-controller="LoginController">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Username:">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type='password' name="pass" ng-model="user.pass" placeholder="Password:">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is the controller...

```
basal.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.submitLogin = function() {
    $http.post('/users', $scope.user)
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      alert("Form post good!");
    })
    .error(function() {
      alert(angular.toJson($scope.user));
    });
  };
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
How does bi-direction works? How do we know of when the data is passed from the controller to the view and the other way round - from the view to the controller. I get the feeling that this is where my misunderstanding lies.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to assign `$scope.user = {};` in the first line of the controller to initialize it.

Comment: Did not work for some reason ..

Answer (score 0):

Your user is never defined or initialised.
Try username and userpass as ng-model definitions like this:

```
<li>
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username:">
</li>
<li>
  <input type='password' name="pass" ng-model="userpass" placeholder="Password:">
</li>
```

And then add accordingly

```
 $http.post('/users', {name: $scope.username, pass: $scope.userpass})
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments, define `$scope.user` as `{}` in your Controller

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `$scope.user = {}` in the first line of your controller.

```
basal.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.submitLogin = function() {
...
```

In your example, `$scope.user == null`. The form doesn't create a new object container for you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it. Did not work! I tried putting `$scope.user = {}` no luck

Comment: what happens if you `console.log($scope.user)` right before the `$http` call?